# ASP.NET write url of page into script data-url

Tags: asp.net

I have an C# ASP.NET website I am working on that i'm struggling to get to do what I need. ASP.NET is new to me so any assistance is greatly appreciated!

I have a social share script that simply posts the page details to a social network, the code looks like this:

```
<script src="share.js" type'="IN/Share" data-url="#PAGE URL#"></script>
```

What I need to do is output the URL of the page into the data-url

I have tried using:

```
<% Response.Write (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri); %>
```

Although this does work, it also outputs the URL to the top of the page, which I don't want. What is a better way to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
<script src="share.js" type="IN/Share" data-url="<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri%>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Javascript to pass the url?

var URL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;